# Need help with using Show to combine 3D graphics with 3D plots

Tags: plotting, graphics

This post brings two related questions. I want to create a combination of Parametric3D plots with a point. I borrowed some code from a tutorial and modified it in order  to add  a point. For some reason, I am not seen or can not get the point displayed.

Here is the code:

```
Show[
  ParametricPlot3D[
    {{Sin[x], x, y}, None, None, None}, {x, -π, π}, {y, 0, 3}],
  ParametricPlot3D[
    {None, {Sin[x - 3], 1 - x, y}, None, None}, {x, 0, 3 π}, {y, 0, 3}],
  ParametricPlot3D[
    {None, {Abs[x - 1], 1 - y^2, y*Pi}, {x - 3, 1 y, Pi}, None}, 
   {x, 0, 3 π}, {y, -2, 3}],
  Graphics3D[PointSize[Large], Point[{2, 2, 1}]],
  ImageSize -> Medium, PlotRange -> All]
```

I can not identify the point in the graph. The second question is about the ise of `None`.  Is it necesarry here?  The documentation in WM is not clear nor usefull in this subject.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 3D graphics, a small sphere looks better than a point. And, no, the `None` arguments aren't required, but removing them changes the coloring of the surfaces.

```
Show[
  ParametricPlot3D[{{Sin[x], x, y}}, {x, -π, π}, {y, 0, 3}], 
  ParametricPlot3D[{{Sin[x - 3], 1 - x, y}}, {x, 0, 3 π}, {y, 0, 3}], 
  ParametricPlot3D[{{Abs[x - 1], 1 - y^2, y π}, {x - 3, 1 y, π}}, {x, 0, 3 π}, {y, -2, 3}],
  Graphics3D[{Red, Sphere[{2, 2, 1}, .2]}],
  ImageSize -> Medium,
  PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 3):

Put the directive and primitives inside `List` in `Graphics3D`, i.e., use

```
Graphics3D[{PointSize[Large], Point[{2, 2, 1}]}]
```

[image]